# issues appending to a multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
$overr=array();

$overr[]=array("selector"=>array('vi'=>mysql_num_rows($myquery),'pes'=>
$pess,'prp'=>mysql_num_rows($my_3_query),'em_t'=>$u_h));//this is in a loop
```

As you can see, I'm trying to append to the array (`$overr`) and add another array inside.

The problem is, its adding 2 arrays inside `$overr`, so when i try using the selector key name to echo a certain array inside `$overr`, it doesn't work, because the key name (selector) is inside another array...if that makes any sense. Well here's the result i get when echoing:

```
echo json_encode ($overr['selector']);//I know i shouldn't be using json_enocde for echoing but its only for temporary testing.
```

The result:

```
null
```

but when i do this:

```
echo json_encode ($overr[9]);
```

it works fine, and prints the 9th array out..

I've tried changing the way i append to the array:

```
$overr[]="selector"=>array('vi'=>mysql_num_rows($myquery),'pes'=>
    $pess,'prp'=>mysql_num_rows($my_3_query),'em_t'=>$u_h);//notice i don't have array at the beginning anymore.
```

And that returns a syntax error.

I need to be able to use the selector as the key.

Am I not appending to the array properly?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use `print_r` instead of `json_encode` and you will see more. Additionally enable error reporting and display, so you actually see what's going wrong: `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: @hakre Hey i just tried that, and i get the error selector is an Undefined index...buts its definitely in the array. Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to the array with [] brackets appends numerically. If your array had one existing entry, the append would add at index 1. This is why `$overr[9]` works.

Your loop would result in `$overr` looking like

```
$overr => array(  
    0 => array("selector" => array(...),
    1 => array("selector" => array(...),
    ...
);
```

In other words, the "selector" key is hidden inside another array and so cannot be accessed directly with `$overr['selector']` but rather `$overr[n]['selector']` with `n` being some index depending on your loop length.

If you want to add to the `selector` key array, you could append like so inside your loop, assuming the `selector` key is already set:

```
$overr['selector'][] = array(...)
```

Please post an example of what you are trying to achieve, if this does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var_dump($overr[$arrayNumber]['selector']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this meets your expectations, but in your first case can make use of `selector` as key. For example getting the first `selector`:

```
$firstSelector = $overr[0]['selector'];
```

If you prefer to write it in some other fashion, e.g. like:

```
$firstSelect = $overr['selector'][0];
```

You need to change the way you build the `$overr` array.

```
//this is in a loop
$overr['selector'][] = array(
    'vi' => mysql_num_rows($myquery),
    'pes' => $pess,
    'prp' => mysql_num_rows($my_3_query)
    'em_t'=>$u_h
);
```

Comment: i cant use a second selector ("[0]") because this array will contain hundreds of arrays with different array keys (i used "selector" as an example). So i need to be able to just do $over['selector'];. Your first example will bring up the first array in $overr but i need to be able to go through every array in $overr and pick one out using the 'selector'. (each array wont have 'selector' as the key, they'll all be unique). thanks